# Autoscroll to object in Panel by C#

Tags: c#, telerik, panel, scrollable, autoscroll

In my application by connecting to database, buttons add to **RadScrollablePanel**. at the other list, button's name are available. when user click and choose from list 2 i want to select the button in RadScrollablePanel.
I found the button by this code :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control[] _controls = MainForm.Controls.Find(PointId.ToString(), true);
foreach (var itemButton in _controls)
{
    if (itemButton.Name == PointId.ToString())
    {
        if (BLL.PropertiesClass.LastFocusedExplorerbarItem != null)
            BLL.PropertiesClass.LastFocusedExplorerbarItem.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        itemButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0x4F, 0x00, 0x60, 0xFF);
        BLL.PropertiesClass.LastFocusedExplorerbarItem = itemButton;
        /* Which Method I Do This*/
        break;
    }
}
```

I test `PerformLayout` and `ScrollControlIntoView` but panel dont scroll there.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code:

```
itemButton.Focus();
itemButton.Select();
PanelOfEachGroup.ScrollControlIntoView(MainForm.ActiveControl);
```